# List of companies in The Netherlands contains German company

Tags: bug, status-declined, jobs, search

I've searched for a [list of companies in The Netherlands](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies?location=Netherlands&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles&pg=2) which also includes [Omikron Data Quality GmbH](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/omikron-data-quality), despite that one being from Germany.

None of their listed cities is even close to The Netherlands.

Comment: The company explicitly lists The Netherlands as a location, at the bottom of the page, as well as the UK, France, Sweden, Italy, Turkey and Poland.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ah! Now I see. But does that make a lot of sense?

Comment: It's up to them really, I'd say.

Comment: On their [website](http://www.omikron.com/Locations.html) they list phone numbers for a number of countries, but they probably don't have offices there. So it's not a bug, it's just misleading on their part.

Comment: Apparently, for whomever filled in that 'location', yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That last location on their company page specifically calls out "Niederlande".